# QT: sqlite and qlist issue

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite, qt

I have a multithread application which accesses a DB from multiple thread, and randomically I fall in this error (not the same query)...

```
__GI___libc_free (mem=0x7fff00042660) at /build/glibc-vjB4T1/glibc-2.28/malloc/malloc.c:3093 
QList<_RData>::node_destruct (this=0x7fffebffce08, from=0x7fffe4037fc0, to=0x7fffe4037fd8) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h:494
QList<_RData>::dealloc (this=0x7fffebffce08, data=0x7fffe4037fb0) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h:865
QList<_RData>::~QList (this=0x7fffebffce08) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h:827
QList<_RData>::operator= (this=0x55555565cd68, other=@0x7fffebffd880: {<QListSpecialMethods<_RoomData>> = {<No data fields>}, {p = {static shared_null = {ref = {atomic = {_q_value = {<std::__atomic_base<int>> = {static _S_alignment = 4, _M_i = -1}, <No data fields>}}}, alloc = 0, begin = 0, end = 0, array = {0x0}}, d = 0x7ffff6ff76c0 <QListData::shared_null>}, d = 0x7ffff6ff76c0 <QListData::shared_null>}}) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h:159
AMProcess::doActionAM (this=0x55555565cc30) at /smart/software/AudioIO/AMProcess.cpp:453
QtPrivate::FunctorCall<QtPrivate::IndexesList<>, QtPrivate::List<>, void, void (AMProcess::*)()>::call(void (AMProcess::*)(), AMProcess*, void**) (f=(void (AMProcess::*)(AMProcess * const)) 0x5555555b943c <AMProcess::doActionAM()>, o=0x55555565cc30, arg=0x7fffebffee40) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobjectdefs_impl.h:134
QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<void (AMProcess::*)()>::call<QtPrivate::List<>, void>(void (AMProcess::*)(), AMProcess*, void**) (f=(void (AMProcess::*)(AMProcess * const)) 0x5555555b943c <AMProcess::doActionAM()>, o=0x55555565cc30, arg=0x7fffebffee40) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobjectdefs_impl.h:167
QtPrivate::QSlotObject<void (AMProcess::*)(), QtPrivate::List<>, void>::impl(int, QtPrivate::QSlotObjectBase*, QObject*, void**, bool*) (which=1, this_=0x555555661cf0, r=0x55555565cc30, a=0x7fffebffee40, ret=0x0) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobjectdefs_impl.h:396
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () at null:
QThread::started(QThread::QPrivateSignal) () at null:
?? () at null:
start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at /build/glibc-vjB4T1/glibc-2.28/nptl/pthread_create.c:486
clone () at /build/glibc-vjB4T1/glibc-2.28/misc/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

This is some snippets of my code

```
rData = DBRManager::ReadRData("R", m_connName);
if (rData.size() > 0) {

}
```

...and this is the query

```
QList<_RData> DBRManager::ReadRData(QString tbName, QString dbName)
{
    QList<_RData> records;
    QSqlQuery query(QSqlDatabase::database(dbName));
    query.setForwardOnly(true);
    query.exec("DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=2");
    query.exec("SELECT * FROM " + tbName);
    
    while (query.next()) {
        _RData data;
        data.id = query.value("id").toInt();
        data.type = query.value("type").toInt();
        records.append(data);
    }
    query.finish();

    return records;
}
```

Comment: Is this `rData` variable used by multiple threads simultaneously?

Comment: No, is  used only in this class, which is associated to only one thread

Comment: Your stack trace is consistent with two threads racing to clean up the same data structure. What are the other threads doing at that time?

Comment: _No, is used only in this class, which is associated to only one thread_ Not that you overlooked something... One `class` doesn't necessarily mean _one instance_. I came to this idea as you mentioned competing accesses to your data base.

Comment: It's strange because this query and this structure is related only to this class, but I'll give it a check

Comment: I double checked it, but which is the line where are indicate the 2 threads?

Comment: Surround your `rdata = ...` line with `QDebug() << "before" << QThread::currentThread()` and the same with `after`.  Do you ever see two consecutive `before` prints?

Comment: Always the same thread: before QThread(0x555555660c00)
after QThread(0x555555660c00)
before QThread(0x555555660c00)
after QThread(0x555555660c00)
before QThread(0x555555660c00)
after QThread(0x555555660c00)